# How to disable a SonarLint rule for the entire project without connecting to a SonarQube server?

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I have an Eclipse project and I use SonarLint to find the bugs in it. I've encountered a lot of cases of false-negatives (like `squid:S1168`) and there isn't really an obvious way to suppress rules like this for the entire project without having to mark every case with either @SuppressWarnings or //NOSONAR.
So is there a way to disable specific rules (not all of them) for a project without having to connect to a SonarQube server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, they have now added this ability and rules can now be disabled on a per-workspace basis using a quickfix option, or going to Window > Preferences > SonarLint > Rules Configuration.